# How to learn ROS if I am a complete novice with no computer science knowledge

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no knowledge in robotics or computer science, and am a windows user. I know a bit of C++. I will have to use ROS for my PhD, and have started learning it. However, so many terms are unknown to me in ROS wiki that I am having a hard time understanding how ROS actually works. How should I overcome this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288374/how-to-learn-ros-if-i-am-a-complete-novice-with-no-computer-science-knowledge./) by [ros_beginner_09](https://answers.ros.org/users/34612/ros_beginner_09/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally I'd say: computer science is not needed, a (strong) programming background will help tremendously though. "a bit of C++" does sound like that could be improved.

I'd start without *any* ROS (seeing as you're starting a PhD, you should have some time to ignore ROS for now), but some good tutorials on:

- Linux (command line and daily usage)
- C++ (perhaps your university has a course)
- perhaps Python
- and as @VictorLamoine suggested: take some time to look into CMake (as the build tool underlying Catkin)

You don't need to be a wizard (so don't overdo looking-for and completing tutorials), but you do need a decent background in these things.

Then look at ROS.

(you could of course always parallelise things, but I've noticed with 'my' students that this can cause them to be overwhelmed by new concepts, and have a hard time properly integrating all the new knowledge).

---

Finally: understand that software engineering (the art of putting programs / structures together in a logical and maintainable way) is just like any other engineering dicipline:

1. identify a problem/task
2. divide it into smaller problems/tasks
3. solve subproblems
4. combine solutions into final solution

ROS ideally helps with steps 2 and 4, by making the effects of dividing solutions into smaller parts almost transparent to your program (ie: communication is taken care of for you).

Programming is just a way to encode your solutions in a format that allows them to be executed by a machine -- in this case a computer.

Learning to program is the process of being able to do that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_beginner_09](https://answers.ros.org/users/34612/ros_beginner_09/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thank you very much for the reply. Do you think using Ubuntu regularly will help me get used to the terminology used in ROS ? Do you have any suggestions regarding good Ubuntu tutorials?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
Immersion always helps (same with learning a foreign language).

re: ubuntu tutorials: no, I wouldn't have anything to recommend.

**Comment by [ros_beginner_09](https://answers.ros.org/users/34612/ros_beginner_09/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thank you very much

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-04-12**:
I find myself using bash commands cd & ls (and their variants) the most. You don't have to be a command line expert.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
I agree, and agreed ("you don't have to be a wizard").

But I would say the following topics are definitely also important:

- copying, moving, creating, deleting files
- (file) permissions
- managing processes (top, kill, etc)
- text manipulation (grep et al)

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-04-12**:
I would add CMake to this list, just before starting the ROS tutorials, learning catkin is hard if you don't know CMake.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
Yes, good suggestion.

But learn CMake with the understanding that Catkin is nothing special: it's a set of convenience macros/functions that help when building ROS pkgs with CMake.

**Comment by [ros_beginner_09](https://answers.ros.org/users/34612/ros_beginner_09/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thank you everyone. I am really glad to see that so many people are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest reading [Programming Robots with ROS by Morgan Quigley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449323898). It's an easy read and teaches ROS in python which is significantly more readable than C++. (Also, I believe it was written by developers in OSRF which is nice.)
Once you're familiar with ROS workflow and concepts you can easily switch to C++.

---

Originally posted by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_beginner_09](https://answers.ros.org/users/34612/ros_beginner_09/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thank you very much. I have started to read the book. But the problem is mainly with keywords. The book also uses some keywords that I do not understand.

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-04-12**:
Can you provide us with some of those keywords?

**Comment by [ros_beginner_09](https://answers.ros.org/users/34612/ros_beginner_09/) on 2018-04-12**:
I just started it yesterday, and now reading catkin, Workspaces, and ROS Packages. So, it says catkin is ROS ''building system''. I could not for example understand what it means to be a building system  (which the book defines as the set of tools that ROS uses to generate executable
programs)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
And that is why I suggested learning about programming, building/compiling programs and all that comes with programming in modern languages *first*. That way you can get comfortable with that terminology (ie: keywords) and then ROS documentation/books will start to make a lot more sense.